# Runtime error

Tags: asp.net

what is the meaning of error,and what do I do for solve this problem ? :

> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you in the error: edit web.config and change the error mode to Off.

For instance, add the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For security reasons you don't want to give out detailed errors externally, so this is usually a better setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will display errors on your development machine or on the server if visited from the server, but redirect external users to a custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

You should not turn CustomErrors off on a production server, as you risk exposing sensitive information through those errors (that's the whole reason it hides them in the first place).  You can implement exception handling & logging to properly diagnose underlying problems on a production server.  Ideally, you'd be able to reproduce the same problem on a development / test server, where CustomErrors could be safely disabled.  But the 'RemoteOnly' default option for CustomErrors still allows you to view the error in production, you just need to be browsing from the local machine (i.e., the web server).

The error you posted itself just means some unhandled exception bubbled up, it could be almost anything.