# Config Error in Server

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am getting the following error

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

And its pointing to 
authentication mode="Windows" line
Can any one help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765796/runtime-error)

Comment: Tried this too customErrors mode="Off". Still getting the same error

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Have you debugged locally?